# React-Native view was rendered with explicitly set width/height but with a 0 flexBasis

Tags: react-native

In React-native 0.39,

I often get this error but I don't really understand why (appart the fact that I didn't set flexGrow...).

Here is the error from the console

```
View was rendered with explicitly set width/height but with a 0 flexBasis. (This might be fixed by changing flex: to flexGrow:) View: <RCTShadowView: 0x6080005a02a0; viewName: RCTView; reactTag: 2608; frame: {{0, 0}, {nan, nan}}>
```

Can someone explain to me why this error is triggered ?

**EDIT**: The error comes from this bit of boilerplate code I added in on the main View :

```
flex: 1,
// remove width and height to override fixed static size
width: null,
height: null,
```

But If someone could shed a light on react-native styling or lead me to good resources, I'll be grateful :)

Comment: dirty way: replace flex: with flexGrow: if you have width and height

Comment: that is what the error says...but why ?

Comment: i meet the same question = =

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to [react-native/React/Views/RCTShadowView.m](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/b9cedaefa61bf1840ef8a7c5e621da4789df8c80/React/Views/RCTShadowView.m#L146), there has comments

```
    This works around a breaking change in css-layout where setting flexBasis needs to 
be set explicitly, instead of relying on flex to propagate.

    We check for it by seeing if a width/height is provided along with a flexBasis  
of 0 and the width/height is laid out as 0.
```

The error is triggered when **flex without defined flexBasis and having either width and height is zero**.

Refer to [react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/LayoutPropTypes.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/5850165795c54b8d5de7bef9f69f6fe6b1b4763d/Libraries/StyleSheet/LayoutPropTypes.js#L364), we know the flexGrow, flexShrink and flexBasis receive values of number.

For visual guide, you might refer to this webpage, [A Visual Guide to CSS3 Flexbox Properties](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation :)

Comment: I get this also after upgrading but it's kind of hard to identify where this is happening:

      `ExceptionsManager.js:71 View was rendered with explicitly set width/height but with a 0 flexBasis. (This might be fixed by changing flex: to flexGrow:) View: <RCTShadowView: 0x6000001b44a0; viewName: RCTView; reactTag: 103; frame: {{0, 0}, {nan, nan}}>`

Comment: Did u set any flex, width and height on the styling triggered the error?

Comment: I'm tryint to identify but it's a large code base, which makes these numeric references extra frustrating. I'm wondering also if there is a default of flex:0 when you set width and height

Comment: try to identify all styling that set flex and also set either width/height

Comment: Can somebody help me ? I'm still getting that error after trying your solutions ! Here's my code : http://pastebin.com/g4Ls8Tms

Comment: @NicolasMeienberger try to identify which flex: 1 causing the error by replaced flex: 1 with flexGrow: 1 one by one? i saw your code has not too many flex

Comment: I identified where this was triggering in my code by putting an xcode breakpoint at this error, and inspecting the `node` pointer with xcode. — By hovering over the `node` variable, you can use xcode to inspect the style attributes set for the problematic view, and then use that to narrow down which js view style could be causing problems.

Comment: @AriaBuckles can you be a little bit more specific? What do you mean "Putting an xcode breakpoint at this error"? How do you even do that?

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `flexDirection: 'row'` solves the problem `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 1):

As the error states - change the 'flex' to 'flexGrow' and the issue is solved.

The difficult part about this is how to **locate** which 'flex' needs to be changed from the whole project. What I did was (using Atom Editor, so 'Find in Project' ...) changing each 'flex:' with 'flexGrow:' (with the ':' at the end you make sure that you change a style) and then simply search the whole project again for a 'flexGrow' and change every 'flexGrow' from each file with 'flex' until you locate the corrupted 'flex'.

I prefer using flex instead of flexGrow, that's why I revert to flex. This is why: [Layout Props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html)

Hope this solves the issues.

Answer (score 0):

In node_modules/react-native/React/Views/RCTShadowView.m add "//" at line 170 like this "// RCTAssert(!YGNodeIsDirty(node), @"Attempt to get layout metrics from dirtied Yoga node.");"