# React-native | View was rendered with explicit set width/height but with a 0 flexBasis

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, react-native

I'm getting the following error on some of my components just after updating my packages (with npm-check-update) everything was working correctly before.

My code : http://pastebin.com/g4Ls8Tms

[image: Error]

[This thread doesn't help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004883/react-native-view-was-rendered-with-explicitly-set-width-height-but-with-a-0-fle)

Comment: Can you post one of the views that you are trying to render (and also the styling)?

Comment: For example a view that generates me that error : http://pastebin.com/g4Ls8Tms